# Java: substring index position

Tags: java

I am confused about the word "index" and "position".

Do they have same meaning for a string?

For example, a given string "Welcome to Java."

Print sub-string of this string at position 5.

What is the output?  "me to Java." ?

Comment: In the context of string manipulation in Java and elsewhere, I have seen both index and position being used.  As for your second question, why don't you try running that code?

Comment: Position and index are probably being used interchangeably. Its *possible* that position is being used with a starting index of 1 instead of 0 but that would be pretty rude of them.

Comment: Thank you, guys. For my second question, I don't understand whether the words "at position 5"  is same as "index 5" or "index 4". I am not sure the output is "me to Java." or "ome to java." ?

Comment: Where are you seeing this usage?  If this is a class assignment, I'd ask the instructor for clarification.  I frankly wouldn't be able to tell exactly what is meant without asking.

Comment: You are right. But I need to finish it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2):

If your string is `Welcome to Java`, `str.substring(5)` will give you the string from index 5 up to the last ch so your output will be `me to Java`. Index starts from 0. Position and index are used in the same context(both start from 0: zeroth position or zeroth index means the same)
Also, `str.substring(start index, end index)` will return you the substring from start index to (end index -1) character. In our case `str.substring(5,14)` will return `me to Jav`

Comment: Thank you. Another question is the sentence "Print sub-string of this string at position 5."   This means I need to write str.substring(5) or str.substring(5, 6)?

Comment: This is a bit ambiguous to me. AT position 5 should only be str.substring(5,6) according to me. But I think you should get this clarified as to what the requirement is. str.substring(5) if it's from position 5 onwards.

Answer (score 2):

In java, the index start from 0.
For the example you gave, let's say you created a string like this.

`String s = "Welcome to Java";`

So, this string has 15 characters in it.
If you call below, it will return 15.

```
s.length()
```

If you draw a table, it should looks like this:

```
    -------------------------------------------
    Index     | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
    ------------------------------------------
    character | W | e | l | c | o | m | e |   |
    -------------------------------------------

    ---------------------------------------
    Index     | 8 | 9 | 10| 11| 12| 13| 14|
    ---------------------------------------
    character | t | o |   | J | a | v | a |
    ---------------------------------------
```

At position 5, since the java start the index with 0, you now know that you have m at position (or index ) at 5, which is 6th character.

```
    ---------------
    Index     | 5 |
    ---------------
    character | m |
    ---------------
```

Usually, in java, position and index means same. However, if the person (whoever asked this question to trick you) say "we use the term 'position 5,' (so he meant 5th character in the string as position 5), then you should start the substring at index of 4.

Yes. it is confused. However, when we say position 5, we usually mean the 6th character where index started at 0.

```
---------------
Index     | 4 |
---------------
character | o |
---------------
```

Now, let's assume that the person (who asked this question) meant the position 5 as 5th character in the string. Then, you will need to think that, your start index to substring is 4.

So, if the person would like to substring from the nth character in a string (where n is a number between 1 to string length), then you want to start substring at n-1, because, as I said, the index starts at 0, in Java.

Now, let's look at the substring. Here is the documentation about the substring method:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Since you would like print a substring of given string, from index 4, you will call...

```
System.out.println(s.substring(4));
```

What is the output? "me to Java." ?
I this case, the output should be

```
"ome to Java"
```

However, if you meant the position 5, same as index 5, then you will call...

```
System.out.println(s.substring(5));
```

Which will print

```
"me to Java"
```

Comment: I almost wanted to give you an upvote until I see `meant the position 5, means 5th character in the string,` No..position 5 means index 5, which is the 6th character.

Comment: I meant someone might trick you by saying "position 5 means the 5th character in the string!" I do know that index (or position) in java start at 0, so position 5 (or index 5) means the 6th character, but I tried to give him an example.

Comment: Thank you very much.Only one question.If I need to print sub-string of this string at position 5, I should use s.substring(5) or s.substring(5, 6)?

Comment: @SongYifeng why don't you try both and see which one is the right one?

Comment: @user3437460  I know the output.My question is I don't understand the sentence "at position 5" meaning.The output should be "m" or "me to Java" ? Thank you.

Comment: @SongYifeng Your question says `print the substring at pos 5` and ***not*** `print the character at pos 5`. So it is very obvious they wanted `me to Java` isn't it?